# Overflow-x:hidden not working in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, scroll, overflow

I've applied this property to the elements: `body` and `html` and still Chrome will let me scroll on the x-axis.
I've tested it in Safari and Firefox and the x-axis scrolling is disabled...

Anyone know what I'm missing?

N.B. Using `overflow: hidden` works but I'd like people to be able to scroll on the y-axis.

Thanks!

Comment: It's working fine for me in Chrome, see -> http://jsfiddle.net/H84pr/

Comment: Seems like it has been fixed then! It certainly wasn't working when I posted this :P

Comment: According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/overflow-x#Browser_compatibility), `overflow-x` works in Chrome as of version 1.0. Maybe this was broken for some time in some versions (it's rather typical for Chrome to have some weird bugs introduced in one version and fixed in next one).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears the problem no longer exists thanks to `@Nelson` pointing this out.
You can see the code working correctly here: http://jsfiddle.net/H84pr

Comment: 3/21/15 - The problem still exists at least on Chrome and Safari in iOS 7.x. I solved it by using `html { overflow-x: hidden; }`.

Comment: The problem persists. Click middle mouse button (scrolling thing) and move mouse to the right. You'll see the issue.

Comment: Thanks! We have 2016 and Chrome version 51 and this is still the only way to fix this …

Answer (score 7):

You can use

```
html { overflow-x: hidden; }​
```

Answer (score 6):

I just encountered this issue when trying to hide some images that I /knew/ would be wider than the body on mobile.

Originally I simply had:

`body { overflow-x: hidden; }`

This didn't work in Chrome, but it did in IE 10.

However, if you then also added:

`html { overflow-x: hidden; }`

The images were correctly hidden in both browsers.